# why is the color of the shape is not changing to red?

Tags: python

### I have been trying to get the color of the square to come out as red, however it only comes out black

```
import turtle

class Shapes:
    def __init__(self, length, sides=4, color="red"):
        self.length = length
        self.sides = sides
        self.color = color

        self.inside_angle_sum = (self.sides - 2) * 180
        self.individual_angle = self.inside_angle_sum / self.sides

    def drawing(self):
        turtle.color = self.color  #do not get why this wont run

        for i in range(self.sides):
            turtle.forward(self.length)
            turtle.left(180 - self.individual_angle)

square = Shapes(100, 4)
square.drawing()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The turtle.color needs ():

```
def drawing(self):
    turtle.color(self.color)
```